# Will an electric shower fry my PC?

Tags: power-supply

In Brazil, showers are all electric. Mine pulls up to 5000W/50A at 120V (actually, 120Vx50A=6000w, but that's how they rated it).

We installed it last week and I told the electrician to make it's circuit independent from all the rest. I think he did it all right, because there's a separate circuit breaker for it, and it works when all the other circuit breakers are off, suggesting the shower is independent. Anyways, I'll climb up there and check later to see what's going on.

I say that because whenever this shower is on the light gets dimmer in my room, which is exactly the effect I didn't want. I once used a multimeter to measure tension on a circuit where this same model of shower was hooked too, and verified that whenever it's on, overall voltage droped by an average of 10V, sometimes 15V, and spiked back up when it was turned off. I'm worried this is going to fry my PC.

My PSU is an XFX TS650, it's based on a seasonic platform (known for top-notch quality) and it exceeds in voltage regulation and noise suppression (it's actually the one top rated 650W PSU I could find back ten) but still I am worried my PC will get fried.

Should I be worried, or my PSU's voltage regulation is enough?
By the way, if that's a problem, what would be a feasible way to fix it?
My only thought was that of calling the electric company and have them install two hots here, that way I could get that shower to spread it's load accross two 120V lines, if that makes any sense at  all. That's expensive though...

Thanks.

Comment: Does your house get 3 phases or only 1?

Comment: The phase question is important because if as I suspect your electric shower is powered from 2 of the 3 phases, a PC on the third phase could see excessive voltage.

Comment: It has only one phase, and that's the reason I think I'm getting brownouts in the first place. Even if the shower is wired separately, it's all linked to the same phase on the street.
In Brazil the electric company provides 2 phases and a neutral in residential districts, and they only wire 1 phase to each house. You have to pay for them come once again and install a second phase if you want.

To get 3 phases you have to buy your own transformer and basically get your "private line", so that's usually just found on industrial parks.

Comment: OK I was under the impression Brazil had 3-phase 127V per phase and 220V phase-phase.  Perhaps they are providing American style split-phase in your neighborhood.   Regardless, if you only have 120V, an electric on-demand heater will put extraordinary load on the service, and 120V is twice as sensitive to voltage drop anyway.  What is the service rating?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Yeah, we use split phase much like (I imagine) in the US. 
And yeah, we only have 127v for the whole house. It's a small house though. As to "service rating" I haven't heard about that term before, what does it mean?

Comment: Service rating is how much current your utility is expecting to supply to your house. If everything is proper, the amps of the main breaker will equal the service rating.  I would not be surprised by "30A" (it's what I have), "60A", "100A", "125A" or even "200A" ... though the higher values seem improbable for a 120V/127V service.  If they wanted to give you that much power, they would give you both phases at half the amps.

Comment: Oh, got it. I think we don't "rate" the systems here unless you request a second phase (then the power company requires a rating).

Turns out I don't need to worry anymore. I call the electrician and explained my concerns, then we did some measurements at the main cables entering the house. We turned device in the house on  (electric oven, TV, PC, both showers, etc) and together they pulled ~42A at 111V.  That's 4662W, although each shower is marked as 5000W, the oven as 2500W, etc, they don't consume half the energy that's written in them.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica as a result, even though I get the lamps to brownout, the voltage drop when the shower is turned on is quite small.

Comment: Ranges and showers are thermostatically controlled so they are cycling on/off as needed.  As such if you did an empty test  (shower water at less than normal intensity, empty burners on the stove) your measured draw would be much lower than realistic.  Measuring and calculation errors are also a possibility, note that ammeters don't display in watts.

Answer (score 5):

I think your PSU should be fine as far as the undervoltage is concerned. After all, what it does is use a transformer to step down high voltage to something lower than then uses switching converters to step it even lower to regulate. If anything your PSU would just brownout, not fry. Not to mention it is rated as low as 100V.

That said, a slow multi-meter won't display line spikes that would actually damage your PSU. You need an oscilloscope that graphs the voltage for that. By spike, I do not mean a rise to normal voltage levels. I mean a rise above normal levels. But an electric heater should be mostly resistive not very inductive to begin with to produce voltage spikes higher than the line voltage.

If you are worried that your PSU's *line regulation* might not be fast enough to react to the rise in input voltage after extended low input voltage and result in too high of a voltage on the output, I wouldn't be too concerned since there are massive output capacitors that can buffer that. It's probably enough to keep your computer on even when lights off then on flicker off. (maybe 1/5th of a second? Certainly 1/10th from my experience)

Comment: *"... use a transformer to step down high voltage to something lower than then uses switching converters to step it even lower to regulate."* No, not if it was bought any time in the last two decades or so. PC power supplies almost universally use a PFC (power factor correction) circuit to convert line voltage to a high DC voltage (380-400 VDC), and then the switching regulator drives a high-frequency transformer to produce the isolated secondary voltage(s). Such supplies are normally "universal input" (wide input voltage range) and are quite forgiving of brownouts and overvoltages.

Comment: @DaveTweed Interesting. Even better.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just buy an extension lead that comes with surge protection and plug your PC into that if you're worried about surges damaging the electronics in your PC? Many of the extension leads sold in the UK advertise this feature, perhaps that is the same in Brazil?

Comment: Yeah, that's another solution I thought about. It's actually cheap around here, but I'd need to ground my PC power outlet. I didn't do it because basically no electrician does it the right way around here, that is, by getting a ground meter and testing the quality of your ground.

To be honest, I never even heard of an electrician that has a ground meter, they usually just stick a 4m copper pole anywhere where there's ground (sometimes in concrete) and say you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about your PC then get a UPS. It will protect you from line glitches and power drops.

Comment: No, that is not what ups's do. That's what some people think they do.  A UPS has one job, switch quickly to a battery fed inverter when power goes out.  When it is on utility power, it is passing the raw power straight through.  Unless it's a super deluxe double-conversion model, but buyers are not fans of those due to the price.

Comment: Power conditioner, not UPS.

Comment: My UPS, an APC BR1500MS2, has input voltage specification 88 - 147V. It boosts and trims out of spec voltage. And the price was quite reasonable.